# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception'

Tags: php, crystal-reports

```html
<?php
$my_report = "D:\\wamp64\www\\report\\test.rpt"; 
$my_pdf = "D:\\wamp64\www\\report\\test.pdf"; 
$o_CrObjectFactory = new COM('CrystalReports115.ObjectFactory.1');
$o_CrApplication =$o_CrObjectFactory->CreateObject("CrystalDesignRunTime.Application"); 
$creport = $o_CrApplication->OpenReport($my_report, 1); 
$o_CrApplication->LogOnServer('localhost','grn','root',''); 
$creport->RecordSelectionFormula="{parameter.id}='1'"; 

//------ This is very important. DiscardSavedData make a 

// Refresh in your data -------

$creport->DiscardSavedData; 

//------ Read the records :-P ------- 

$creport->ReadRecords(); 

//------ Export to PDF ------- 

$creport->ExportOptions->DiskFileName=$my_pdf; 
$creport->ExportOptions->FormatType=31; 
$creport->ExportOptions->DestinationType=1; 
$creport->Export(false); 

//------ Release the variables 
$creport = null; 
$crapp = null; 
$ObjectFactory = null; 
?>
```

I am trying to run php mysql below code for output pdf report through crystal report but Fatal error occurred. [error image ][1]please help me. I am using PHP 5.6.31 crystal report 11.5.10.1263.

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: how can i add code ? sir please help my mobile no : +91-9327823000

Comment: Edit this post to add code.

Comment: I add code here sir please help

Comment: Sir will you please give you id so I can send code and error image

Comment: I am using Windows 10 64 bit operating system

Comment: Hello nobody helps me please help me to resolve issue